# not primitive types in Room database migration

Tags: android, android-room

I am adding new entity FeedItem in my Room database and writing a migration for it.

Problem: I have a Date type in my FeedItem class, which is not primitive type. What is the proper way to write migration in this case?

```
@Entity(tableName = "FeedItem")
public class FeedItem implements Item, Votable {

private int id;
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "feedItemRowIndex")
private int rowIndex;
private int toId;
private int fromId;
private Date date;
...
```

my migration currently looks like this.

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE FeedItem (feedItemId INTEGER, " +
                "feedItemRowIndex INTEGER, " +
                "feedVotes INTEGER" +
                "feedVote INTEGER" +
                "toId INTEGER" +
                "fromId INTEGER" +
                "date Date" + // i need to change this row
                 ...
                "PRIMARY KEY (feedItemRowIndex))"
```

and here converter for Date type

```
public class DateConverter {
@TypeConverter
public static Date toDate(Long timestamp) {
    return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
}

@TypeConverter
public static Long toTimestamp(Date date) {
    return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
}
}
```

thanks!

Comment: If it is long then it is most likely INTEGER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite easy. Room generates primitive type appropriate to converter type.

So in my case type is INTEGER. Thanks to @EpicPandaForce for comment

Answer (score 0):

If room.schemaLocation is set in your build.gradle file, then you can look at the generated schema and copy the exact sql that Room would use to create the table.
[Complete example here](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2)